# allow acces to files only via cgi

Tags: django, .htaccess, apache2

I ve got a working django.cgi file which allows serving content.
From many tutorials i got the following snippet for my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ django.cgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

This snippet allows acces to any files directly (without having to use the cgi script).

I would like to forbid direct access to any file so that it is only possible to pass the file to the cgi script except all the files in the /static directory. I tried:

```
order allow,deny
deny from all
<Files django.cgi>
  order allow,deny
  allow from all
</Files>
```

But with this solution i can call www.mysite.com/django.cgi, while www.mysite.com is forbidden. Is there a proper way to pass anything to the cgi script (except for a static folder)?

*** EDIT *** 
For any Reason, if I drop the RewriteCond `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` , I am getting a 500 Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`.

That condition is excluding existing files from the rule, Should be just like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !django\.cgi  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ django.cgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, I completed the question to that effect. Removing the RewriteCond leads to a server error.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it works. I just do not understand, why:
If I remove `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !django\.cgi  [NC]` and call any url, the rewrite rule applies and by then it should finish, according to mod_rewrite description: "_[...] If the Pattern matches, mod_rewrite checks for rule conditions. If none are present, the URL will be replaced with a new string, constructed from the Substitution string, and mod_rewrite goes on to the next rule._" Could you please explain this?

Comment: Well, the problem is it doesn't stop the process: *"...and then initiates a new internal sub-request with the new URL..."* Check this document with [mod_rewrite technical details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/tech.html)